# How to make a listbox item not duplicate itself to the next line of the listbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

so I am adding an item in a listbox by clicking an image.
If the item gets clicked or added multiple times,it duplicates itself to the next line of the listbox. What I want is the item to have a counter that will count the number of instance it was clicked.

here's my code so far:

```
int ctr = 1;
 private void item_img1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!orderList.Items.Contains(item1.Text))
            {
                orderList.Items.Add(item1.Text + ctr);
                ctr++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you want to allow adding exactly 1 item (of this images type), why not simply remove the click event after successfully adding the first instance?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're not actually adding `item1.Text`; you're adding `item1.Text + ctr`.  That's why your `if` clause isn't keeping you from adding duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
class ItemWrapper
{
    public object item;
    public string text;
    public int ctr = 1;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text + " (" + ctr + ")";
    }
}

private void item_img1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var itm in orderList.Items)
        if ((itm as ItemWrapper).text == item1.Text)
        {
            (itm as ItemWrapper).ctr++;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    if (!found)
        orderList.Items.Add(new ItemWrapper() { item = item1, text = item1.Text, ctr = 1 });
}
```

Where ItemWrapper is wrapper of your `item` object and overriding `ToString()` method in it allows `listBox` to display object as your defined format.